# Echo once with OR statement if value equals to

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

am a total noob in PHP. So bear with me ;-). However after searching here, I was able to change initial code to below.

1. My issue is that 'My message here' will appear several times if value "file" is found in various fields value. What I need is that message appears only once whenever at least one field contains 'file'
2. Am sure below codes can greatly be shortened.

```
        <?php if($this->item->params->get('itemExtraFields') && isset($this->item->extra_fields) && count($this->item->extra_fields)): ?>
        
        <?php foreach ($this->item->extra_fields as $key => $extraField): ?>
        <?php if($extraField->name == "Original" OR $extraField->name == "Wallpaper"): ?>
        <?php if (strpos($extraField->value, 'file') !== false): ?><?php echo 'My message here'; ?>
        <?php endif; ?><?php endif; ?><?php endforeach; ?>
        
        <h3 class="extra3">Gears</h3>
        <?php foreach ($this->item->extra_fields as $key => $extraField): ?>
         <?php if($extraField->name == "Camera"): ?><span class="rft"><strong><?php echo $extraField->name; ?>:</strong> <?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
         <?php if($extraField->name == "Lens"): ?><span class="rft"><strong><?php echo $extraField->name; ?>:</strong> <?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
         <?php if($extraField->name == "Aperture"): ?><span class="rft"><strong><?php echo $extraField->name; ?>:</strong> <?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
         <?php if($extraField->name == "Exposure"): ?><span class="rft shifts"><strong><?php echo $extraField->name; ?>:</strong> <?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
         <?php if($extraField->name == "ISO"): ?><span class="rft"><strong><?php echo $extraField->name; ?>:</strong> <?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
         <?php if($extraField->name == "Focal Length"): ?><span class="rft shifts"><strong><?php echo $extraField->name; ?>:</strong> <?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
         <?php if($extraField->name == "HDR"): ?><span class="rft"><strong><?php echo $extraField->name; ?>:</strong> <?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
        
        <h3 class="extra4">Download</h3>
        <?php foreach ($this->item->extra_fields as $key => $extraField): ?>
         <?php if($extraField->name == "Original"): ?><span class="rft"><strong><?php echo $extraField->name; ?>:</strong> <?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
         <?php if($extraField->name == "File Size"): ?><span class="rft"><strong><?php echo $extraField->name; ?>:</strong> <?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
         <?php if($extraField->name == "Dimensions (px)"): ?><span class="rft"><strong><?php echo $extraField->name; ?>:</strong> <?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
         <?php if($extraField->name == "Wallpaper"): ?><span class="rft shift2"><strong><?php echo $extraField->name; ?>:</strong> <?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
         <?php if($extraField->name == "Format"): ?><span class="rft shifts"><strong><?php echo $extraField->name; ?>:</strong> <?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
          
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're doing it in a foreach it will get printed every time. So if you need to display it only once, you need to store the information that you already displayed it somewhere:

```php
<?php $displayedFileInfo = false; ?>
<?php foreach ($this->item->extra_fields as $key => $extraField): ?>
<?php if($extraField->name == "Original" OR $extraField->name == "Wallpaper"): ?>
<?php if (strpos($extraField->value, 'file') !== false && !$displayedFileInfo): ?><?php echo 'My message here'; $displayedFileInfo = true; ?>
<?php endif; ?><?php endif; ?><?php endforeach; ?>
```

Another possibility would be to break out of the loop since you're not doing anything else than printing the one information:

```php
<?php foreach ($this->item->extra_fields as $key => $extraField): ?>
<?php if($extraField->name == "Original" OR $extraField->name == "Wallpaper"): ?>
<?php if (strpos($extraField->value, 'file') !== false): ?><?php echo 'My message here'; break; ?>
<?php endif; ?><?php endif; ?><?php endforeach; ?>
```

Few other considerations:

1. the code is hard to read, try switching to this format:

```php
<?php

$displayedFileInfo = false;
foreach($this->item->extra_fields as $key => $extraField) {
    if ($extraField->name == "Original" || $extraField->name == "Wallpaper") {
        if (strpos($extraField->value, 'file') !== false && !$displayedFileInfo) {
            echo 'My message here';
            $displayedFileInfo = true;
        }
    }
}
```

2. Don't use `and` and `or`, use `&&` (and) and `||` (or). These two behave a little differently and most of the time you want the behavior of `&&` and `||`.
3. Use switch instead of multiple if statements:

```php
<?php

switch($extraField->name) {
    case "Camera":
        echo "<span class='rft'><strong>{$extraField->name}:</strong> {$extraField->value}</span>";
        break;
        // etc.
}
```

Comment: Breaking out of the loop would make more sense than keeping track if the value was displayed. That way we don't unnecessarily iterate the rest of the array.

Comment: @El_Vanja true, in this case yes, will update.